# Constructing a "parent/child" system with a single class

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to create a 'skeletal' like system using class `Bone` and having the "primary" bone's children consist of all other bones that are connected.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bone body = new Bone("primary", null);
        Bone leftArm1 = new Bone("left_arm_1", body);
        Bone leftArm2 = new Bone("left_arm_2", leftArm1);
        Bone rightArm1 = new Bone("right_arm_1", body);
        Bone rightArm2 = new Bone("right_arm_2", rightArm1);

        List<Bone> bones = new ArrayList<Bone>();
        for(Bone child : body.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(child.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

```
public class Bone {
    private Bone parent = null;
    private String name = null;
    private List<Bone> children = new ArrayList<Bone>();
    public Bone(String name, Bone parent) {
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = parent;
        if(parent != null) {
            parent.addChild(this);
        }
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public Bone getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }
    public boolean hasParent() {
        if(this.parent != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public List<Bone> getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    }
    public boolean hasChildren() {
        if(this.children.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public void addChild(Bone child) {
        this.children.add(child);
    }
}
```

The current program is outputting...

```
left_arm_1
right_arm_1
```

when it should be outputting...

```
left_arm_1
left_arm_2
right_arm_1
right_arm_2
```

how would I make the program output the correct strings?

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you're asking of it:  Print the names of the children of "primary".  It sounds like you also want it to print out the names of the children's children (and children's children's children, etc).  I'd suggest having a `printChildren()` method on `Bone` that prints the current bone's name, and then calls `printChildren()` on all the bone's children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use recursion

```
   public void printBones(Bone bone) {
        if(bone == null) {
            return;
        }

        List<Bone> children = bone.getChildren();
        if(children != null && children.size() > 0) {
            for(Bone bone : children) {
                printBones(bone);  
            }
        }

        System.out.println(bone.getName());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `body` has only 2 children, the output is only  `left_arm_1  right_arm_1`

If you want to print all children, you need to do it in recursion for all children of the children and so on.